# Retrieve app id from app address (algorand)

Tags: blockchain, algorand

Exploring blockchain dev. Just tried coding on Algorand and am trying to get the app ID from its address. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it is not possible without an off-chain lookup.